# PHP MySQL Update problem with multiple condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql, while-loop

I need some solutions how to make some update database.

Database structure:

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

[image: Picture 3]

I will need update **SORT** column depend on **season_num** and **series_id**.

**PICTURE 1 STORY**

Picture 1 is showing 3 different **series_id** witch first is (*with series_id 2*), second is (*with series_id 3*) and the third is (*with series_id 4*)

In this case i have only 1 **season_num** per **series_id** and **SORT** was good.

**PICTURE 2 STORY**

Picture 2 is showing that same **series_id** have 2 **season_num** and **SORT** is also good.

*I need make SORT to start from 1 and end with last ROW by **season_num**.*

**PICTURE 3 STORY**

And on this picture start the problem, this **series_id** have more **season_num** and there is problem for me.

Problem start from **season_num** 3. **SORT** was continue from **season_num** 2 but it need be restarted and start from 1 not from 13.

**PROBLEM TOTAL STORY**

In picture case i have total **season_num = 3** by one **series_id**, i have also a lot of more **season_num** by other **series_id**.

**season_num** need start from 1 on all new **season_num**.

***season_num*** 1,2,3,4...60 all in first row need to start with 1

**CODE:**

**Note my code not work, if you have any other idea just tell me!!*

```
//gritpas public fix
$serije_fix = $db->query("SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE() AND TABLE_NAME = 'series'");
$inc = 1;
$rows_fetch = $serije_fix->fetch_assoc();
$max_id=$rows_fetch['AUTO_INCREMENT'];

while ($inc != $max_id){
    $inc2 = 1;
    $inc3 = 1;
    $serije_fix2 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM series_episodes WHERE series_id='$inc'");

        while ($rows_fetch2 = $serije_fix2->fetch_assoc()){
            $serije_id = $rows_fetch2['id'];
                if ($rows_fetch2['season_num'] > '1'){
                      $db->query("UPDATE `series_episodes` SET `sort`='$inc3' WHERE id='$serije_id'");
                            $inc3 ++;
                   }else{
                          $db->query("UPDATE `series_episodes` SET `sort`='$inc2' WHERE id='$serije_id'");
                    }
        $inc2++;
        }
    $inc++;
}
```

Comment: Kindly donot post images of code, also refer to this [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have the database do the sorting for you. Change your `serjie_fix2` query to:

```
SELECT * FROM series_episodes WHERE series_id='$inc' ORDER BY series_id, season_num, stream_id
```

Then, get rid of `$inc3` and the `if/else` clause:

```
while ($inc != $max_id){
  $inc2 = 1;
  $prev_season_num = 0;
  $serije_fix2 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM series_episodes WHERE series_id='$inc' ORDER BY series_id, season_num, stream_id");

  while ($rows_fetch2 = $serije_fix2->fetch_assoc()){
    $serije_id = $rows_fetch2['id'];
    if ($rows_fetch2['season_num'] != $prev_season_num) {
      $inc2 = 1;
    }
    $db->query("UPDATE `series_episodes` SET `sort`='$inc2' WHERE id='$serije_id'");
    $inc2++;
    $prev_season_num = $rows_fetch2['season_num'];
  }
  $inc++;
```